# Patent warning for using nonce feature of Content-Security-Policy

Tags: content-security-policy

Just asking if anyone has come across something like this and I'm really not sure what part of stackexchange this really fits in...

I'm not going to post details of the company or patent information, but I've just received a recorded letter through the post informing me that the sending UK company has UK & US patents covering certain features of Content-Security-Policy and that I should be paying license fees if I want to use it.

> It may surprise you to learn that this important feature is an embodiment of an invention devised by myself prior to publication of CSP 2.0 [snip] patented and protected by UK & US patent laws

> and secondly where they are not interested in using {Propriety software} urge them to register with {Sending Company} and pay a very reasonable license fee for the use of our intellectual property

Most of the letter seems to be trying to push their own implementation which apparently has additional features and better (old) browser support over CSP.

To be honest I would rather just drop the CSP header, but it seems incredibly dubious that they are trying to claim license fees for something that is part of a massively widely used w3 standard.

It seems that they have simply done a web crawl and identified sites that are providing specific values in the CSP header so I would be surprised if other people have not received a similar letter.

Comment: You absolutely should name and shame the sender.

Comment: Sounds like a scam